# Behat not recognising :arg style tokens

Tags: php, behat

I've just read that I can use tokens in the format of :argument in my context method Given annotations, however when I do this it's telling me the step is undefined...

```
/**
 * @Given I am logged in as :username
 */
public function iAmLoggedInAs( $username )
{
    // ...
}
```

This returns `Undefined step "I am logged in as 'disco-superuser'"`, however ...

```
/**
 * @Given /^I am logged in as "([^"]*)"$/
 */
public function iAmLoggedInAs( $username )
{
    // ...
}
```

... works fine.

What am I missing here.

Behat version: 2.5.3

Comment: Can you point me to a documention that describes the `:name` notation?

Comment: Are you sure behat provides this feature? I couldn't find it in [docs](http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/guides/2.definitions.html).

Comment: I found it here... http://bit.ly/1qbz4dp  I was assuming that, as I when you go to the Docs link, it links to a URI containing 2.5, I thought v3 was not out yet, thus the docs with /latest/ would apply to v2.5.  Perhaps that was an invalid assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are "unsure": the feature is called turnip pattern, this is new in Behat 3. You can read a little about it in the [official docs](http://docs.behat.org/en/v3.0/guides/2.definitions.html#creating-your-first-step-definition) or dig the [`TurnipPatternPolicy`](https://github.com/Behat/Behat/blob/a996f07b052f61cf224c4494d06c424bde1b341f/src/Behat/Behat/Definition/Pattern/Policy/TurnipPatternPolicy.php) class for more details.

<del>It throws undefined step definition exception because you are using single quotes, given you provided the correct details. Check again with double quotes, must fix it.</del> The `TOKEN_REGEX` in the [`TurnipPatternPolicy`](https://github.com/Behat/Behat/blob/a996f07b052f61cf224c4494d06c424bde1b341f/src/Behat/Behat/Definition/Pattern/Policy/TurnipPatternPolicy.php) class allows for single and double quotes, as well as no quotes at all, the [documentation](http://docs.behat.org/en/latest/guides/2.definitions.html#creating-your-first-step-definition) also gives an example of all three cases, which I completely ignored.

Also, in case some one tries, you cannot combine different types of pattern in one definition (turnip and regex that is), [like I did](https://github.com/Behat/Behat/issues/555). Read  [Konstantin's answer](https://github.com/Behat/Behat/issues/555#issuecomment-46728454) on why and other useful information.

Comment: Ah, so it's because I'm using v2.5.  I thought that, since the 'Docs' link on the Behat site linked to a /2.5/ URI that this was the latest version, so the doc page I found with /latest/ in the uri was for v2.5.  That seesm to have been an invalid assumption.  A small point of note on your advice... the (v3) docs sat you can use double or single quotes for strings (see http://bit.ly/1qbzAYX for reference).  Thanks for the info.

Comment: @TobyG, hey man, thanks for pointing out. I completely overlooked that part.